# output captcha image with font cause apache "dead"

Tags: php, captcha, phalcon, imagick

```
 $image = new \Imagick();
 $draw = new \ImagickDraw();

 $fillColor = new \ImagickPixel('black');
 $bgColor = new \ImagickPixel('gray');
 $fontSize = 24;
 $text = 'helloworld';
 $text = substr($text, 0, rand(1, 10));
 $font = '/home/koogua/font/yy.ttf';

 $draw->setFont($font);
 $draw->setFontSize($fontSize);
 $draw->setFillColor($fillColor);
 $draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
 $draw->setTextAntialias(true);
 $draw->setgravity(\Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
 $draw->annotation(0, 0, $text);

 $metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);

 $image->newImage($metrics['textWidth'] + 30, $metrics['textHeight'] + 10, $bgColor);
 $image->setImageFormat('png');
 $image->drawImage($draw);

 $draw->destroy();

 // $image->writeImage('test.png');

 header('Content-Type: image/png');
 echo $image->getImageBlob();
 exit;

  // $this->response->setContentType( 'image/png');
  // $this->response->setContent($image->getImageBlob());
  // $this->response->send();
```

enviroment: phalcon

output with font  : refresh the page 1- 5 times, capcha image is ok,  after 5 times, apache "dead"

output without font : ok

save file : ok

**when I set font size to 18, everything is ok, other font size will cause apache "dead", seems 18 is the only luck number, very strange, is it ?**

---

enviroment: another php framework (rewrite is enabled)

output with font  : ok

output without font : ok

save file: ok

---

enviroment: pure php

output with font  : ok

output without font : ok

save file: ok

can someone test the above code ?

Comment: Did you see apache error log?

Comment: i refreshed more than 50 times& there is no error on apache!

Comment: @M2sh  error log: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: Ok, it seems your imagemagick library returns the response to php in long time. so what operating system you use? & how install the imagemagick library?

Comment: @m2sh thank you very much, ubuntu14.04, apt-get install php5-imgick, I change another common font, everything is ok now, but what cofuse me is that why only error displayed in phalcon with the "bad font" ?

Comment: i don't  know why only phalcon have error, may be it's for initial settings in phalcon php c-extension & we can't finding whats that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there something wrong with the font file, change to another common font, everything is ok now.